# `load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ApplicationRecord (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, upgrade

After Upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0, I received this error:

```
`load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ApplicationRecord (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is such a simple thing to miss so I thought I should mentioned it.

If you tried to "Auto Replace" all of your models from:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
```

to

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
```

chances are, you probably replaced your `app/models/application_record.rb` file with the same, and it looks like this right now:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ApplicationRecord
```

fix it back to read:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and you should be good to go!